# how to cleanly remove directories in my $home directory

Tags: unix, ksh

I pulled in a RCS repository and it has a lot of crud in it - I would like to remove any directory which has no files in it..

also I want to remove all RCS directories..

thanks

Comment: Did you made some research before post your question? What have you already tried to remove the directories?

Answer (score 0):

have you try

```
cd "parent directory"
find . -type d -exec rmdir {}\;
```

you can also do

```
find . -exec rmdir {}\;
```

rmdir will fail if there are file in a directory..

also - you can for RCS do

```
find . -name RCS -exec rm -rf {}\;
```

Comment: hi - thanks.. I just found the same in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/how-to-delete-directories-based-on-find-output